# Magento2 - How to hide price until login by using custom block about customer session?

Tags: magento2, session

I'm trying to hide prices until the customer logs in to our website. 
To meet this goal, I'm willing to use customer sessions and if session is true, my product detail page shows the price. Or not, just show a label written as 'login to see price'.

When I ran a Magento 1 website, it was much easier to implement this module but it has been tough to me with the same project under a different development environment.

### My Website is now:

1. Use customizable theme from other template company (the vendor name is **Alothemes**)
2. Already overwrote default `.phtml` file that has price information. I mean some snippet code should be inserted to this file.
3. I created a own block (my company name is **Kbethos**) functioning that it brings customer session exists or not
4. Report says:

   a:4:{i:0;s:37:"Object DOMDocument should be created.";i:1;s:11753:"#0 /home/staging/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Config/Reader.php(95): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Config\DomMerger->getDom()
5. Log says:

   [2017-10-18 18:37:18] main.CRITICAL: Invalid block type: Kbethos\Session\Block [] []

Could you have a look my code?

### TEMPLATE CODE

> app\design\frontend\Alothemes\default\Magento_Catalog\layout\default.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
            <block class="Kbethos\Session\Block\Session" before="-" name="my.custome.block" cacheable="false" template="product\price\amount\default.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> app\design\frontend\Alothemes\default\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\price\amount\default.html

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>

<?php /** @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\Amount $block */ ?>

<!-- USE CUSTOM BLOCK -->
<?php $customerSession = $block->getCustomerSession(); ?>
<!-- IF SESSION EXISTST -->
<?php if(custommerSession) : ?>
    <span class="price-container <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getAdjustmentCssClasses() ?>"
        <?php echo $block->getSchema() ? ' itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer"' : '' ?>>
        <?php if ($block->getDisplayLabel()): ?>
            <span class="price-label"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getDisplayLabel(); ?></span>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <span <?php if ($block->getPriceId()): ?> id="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getPriceId() ?>"<?php endif;?>
            <?php echo($block->getPriceDisplayLabel()) ? 'data-label="' . $block->getPriceDisplayLabel() . $block->getPriceDisplayInclExclTaxes() . '"' : '' ?>
            data-price-amount="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getDisplayValue(); ?>"
            data-price-type="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getPriceType(); ?>"
            class="price-wrapper <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getPriceWrapperCss(); ?>"
        <?php echo $block->getSchema() ? ' itemprop="price"' : '' ?>>
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->formatCurrency($block->getDisplayValue(), (bool)$block->getIncludeContainer()) ?>
    </span>

    <?php if ($block->hasAdjustmentsHtml()): ?>
            <?php echo $block->getAdjustmentsHtml() ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($block->getSchema()): ?>
           <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getDisplayCurrencyCode()?>" />
        <?php endif; ?>
    </span>
<!-- SESSION DOESN'T EXIST-->
<?php else : ?>
    <span class="price-container">
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo 'Login to see price' ?>"
    </span>
<?php endif;?>
```

### CUSTOM BLOCK CODE

> app\code\Kbethos\Session\Block\Session.php

```
<?php
namespace Kbethos\Session\Block;


/**
 * Customer edit form block
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.DepthOfInheritance)
 */
class Session extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    protected $_customerSession;

    /**
     * DataDummy constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct (
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_isScopePrivate = true;
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }


    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getCustomerSession()
    {

        /** Bug in magento 2 for get session with full page cache enabled */
        return $this->_customerSession->getCustomer();
    }

}
```

I have `etc/di.xml`, `etc/module.xml`, `composer.json`, `registration.php` for this custom block.

**How can I handle it?**

Comment: `session.php` should be named as `Session.php`

Comment: Yes i did. By the way, it doesn't work. Do you find any issue in this code?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
namespace Kbethos\Session\Block;


/**
 * Customer edit form block
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.DepthOfInheritance)
 */
class Session extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    protected $_customerSession;

    /**
     * DataDummy constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct (
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_isScopePrivate = true;
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }


    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getCustomerSession()
    {

        /** Bug in magento 2 for get session with full page cache enabled */
        return $this->_customerSession->getCustomer();
    }

}
```

its working for me